# Making SSH from a jumpserver(linux) to Devices(modem) using Python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to execute few commands in a Jump server(linux) to access certain devices(modems) using SSH. And then get some device details after login in to the device(modem)
I'm using Paramiko to access jump server, the below code

```
import paramiko
import time
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('jump server ip', username='user', password='pass', key_filename='D:\New folder\id_rsa')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('pwd') #prints the correct pwd
```

This works fine
So from the jump server I need to ssh a device(modem) using its ipv6 mac address.
the command is

```
sudo stbsshv6 'ipv6address'/n
```

But when I execute any command after ssh the device(modem), I'm not getting anything in stdout. **Example:**

```
import paramiko
import time
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('jump server ip', username='user', password='pass', key_filename='D:\New folder\id_rsa')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('sudo stbsshv6 "ipv6address"')
stdin.write('ifconfig wlan0\n')#some working command
print stdout.readlines() # prints nothing
```

I can do manually the above steps using putty,

I'm new to python, can anyone suggest the right solution for this or any alternate way is also great. Thanks

Comment: What's in *stderr*?

Comment: @EmilyE. It captures the errors if any when executing ssh.exec_command()

Comment: `stdin.write('ifconfig wlan0\n')` Try `\r` instead of `\n`. The enter key actually produces \r (Ctrl-M, aka carriage return).